# Eclipse Project MenuManager MenuListener MenuShown?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to override `org.eclipse.ui.project.cleanAction`.

Simple `org.eclipse.ui`. commands & handlers doesnt work because of structure of `WorkbenchActionBuilder`. I have solved it with code :

```
 MenuManager menu = (MenuManager) ((WorkbenchWindow)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()).getActionBars().getMenuManager();
    menu = (MenuManager) menu.find( "project" );
    menu.replaceItem( "buildClean", new ActionContributionItem( new ABCBuildCleanAction(  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow() ) ) );
```

Now how can I make this code piece work when I press Project from menu? This is a MenuManager and I thought MenuAdapter (MenuListener) menuShown method can help but how can I make it run? I searched for a solution via `plugin.xml` Extensions but as which extension point should I add it?

Any Idea? Please don't hesitate to ask for more information...

Comment: Note that `WorkbenchWindow` is an **internal** class, you are breaking the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by trying to use it.

Comment: It is an internal class but this trick works and it looks that this is the only way to override Project->Clean... I want this code work before the Project-> Clean... button but how ? Any Idea ?

Comment: Internal classes may be changed at any time. WorkbenchWindow in particular was completely rewritten between Eclipse 3 and 4. This resulted in several products who were ignoring the rules and using it ending up with severe problems.

Comment: I see, we are using WorkbenchWindow to gain access to MenuManager. There is no modification to the class. Do you have any idea about the solution ?

Comment: No I don't know of a solution. Can you not use the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.cleanUps` extension point to add to the existing cleanups.

Comment: org.eclipse.jdt.ui.cleanUps wont work for us. Because we need to change the clean dialog (That opens up when we press Project->Clean...). Do you know why it is not a global action like Copy/Paste ?

Answer (score 0):

We put that code piece under : 
Bundle-Activator : in MANIFEST.MF file (It is the Activator.) That XXPlugin class extends AbstractUIPlugin class. In the start method I put my code to work.

This solved my problem, now when eclipse starts It loads this code and my code works instead of CleanDialog class...

ilke